# How to delete redundant values based on other value?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, filter, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

In the below dataframe, there are several `apartments` with different `job`'s:

```
+---+---------+------+                                                                 
|id |apartment|job   |
+---+---------+------+
|1  |Ap1      |dev   |
|2  |Ap1      |anyl  |
|3  |Ap2      |dev   |
|4  |Ap2      |anyl  |
|5  |Ap2      |anyl  |
|6  |Ap2      |dev   |
|7  |Ap2      |dev   |
|8  |Ap2      |dev   |
|9  |Ap3      |anyl  |
|10 |Ap3      |dev   |
|11 |Ap3      |dev   |
+---+---------+------+
```

For each apartment, the number of rows with `job='dev'` should be equal to the number of rows with `job='anyl'` (like for Ap1). How to delete the redundant rows with `'dev'` in all the apartments?

The expected result:

```
+---+---------+------+                                                                 
|id |apartment|job   |
+---+---------+------+
|1  |Ap1      |dev   |
|2  |Ap1      |anyl  |
|3  |Ap2      |dev   |
|4  |Ap2      |anyl  |
|5  |Ap2      |anyl  |
|6  |Ap2      |dev   |
|9  |Ap3      |anyl  |
|10 |Ap3      |dev   |
+---+---------+------+
```

I guess I should use Window functions to deal with that, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: What if you have more of 'anyl' than 'dev'?

Comment: It doesnt metter, I just want to delete the redunant dev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you first need to find out how many 'anyl' do you have for every 'apartment' and then use it to delete all the excess 'dev'. So, first, aggregation, then `join` and then window function `row_number` before you can filter out what you don't need.

Setup:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 'Ap1', 'dev'),
     (2, 'Ap1', 'anyl'),
     (3, 'Ap2', 'dev'),
     (4, 'Ap2', 'anyl'),
     (5, 'Ap2', 'anyl'),
     (6, 'Ap2', 'dev'),
     (7, 'Ap2', 'dev'),
     (8, 'Ap2', 'dev'),
     (9, 'Ap3', 'anyl'),
     (10, 'Ap3', 'dev'),
     (11, 'Ap3', 'dev')],
    ['id', 'apartment', 'job']
)
```

Script:

```py
df_grp = df.filter(F.col('job') == 'anyl').groupBy('apartment').count()
df = df.join(df_grp, 'apartment', 'left')

w = W.partitionBy('apartment', 'job').orderBy('id')
df = df.withColumn('_rn', F.row_number().over(w))
df = df.filter('_rn <= count')
df = df.select('id', 'apartment', 'job')

df.show()
# +---+---------+----+
# | id|apartment| job|
# +---+---------+----+
# |  2|      Ap1|anyl|
# |  1|      Ap1| dev|
# |  4|      Ap2|anyl|
# |  5|      Ap2|anyl|
# |  3|      Ap2| dev|
# |  6|      Ap2| dev|
# |  9|      Ap3|anyl|
# | 10|      Ap3| dev|
# +---+---------+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a left semijoin instead of `groupBy`+`filter` combo suggested by @ZygD might be more efficient:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import Window
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> df1 = df.withColumn('rn', row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('apartment', 'job').orderBy('id')))
>>> df2 = df1.join(df1.alias('dfa').where("job='anyl'"),(df1.apartment==dfa.apartment)&(df1.rn==dfa.rn),'leftsemi')
>>> df2.show(truncate=False)
+---+---------+----+---+
|id |apartment|job |rn |
+---+---------+----+---+
|1  |Ap1      |dev |1  |
|2  |Ap1      |anyl|1  |
|3  |Ap2      |dev |1  |
|4  |Ap2      |anyl|1  |
|5  |Ap2      |anyl|2  |
|6  |Ap2      |dev |2  |
|9  |Ap3      |anyl|1  |
|10 |Ap3      |dev |1  |
+---+---------+----+---+
```